# How to specify an array element for ComplexType

Tags: entity-framework

So I have the following ComplexType:

```cs
[ComplexType]
public class TransactionSettings
{
    [Display(Name = "Minimum Order Amount"), Column(TypeName = "MONEY")]
    public decimal MinimumOrder { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Payment Provider")]
    public PaymentProvider PaymentProvider { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Provider Settings")]
    public ProviderSettings ProviderSettings { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Accepted Credit Cards")]
    public CreditCards[] AcceptedCreditCards { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Taxable States")]
    public States[] SalesTaxStates { get; set; }
}

public enum CreditCards
{
    MasterCard,
    Visa,
    [Description("American Express")]
    AmericanExpress,
    Discover
}

public enum States
{
    [Description("Alabama")]
    AL,
    [Description("Alaska")]
    AK,
    [Description("Arizona")]
    AZ,
    //.
    //.
    //.
    [Description("Wisconsin")]
    WI,
    [Description("Wyoming")]
    WY
}
```

The array indicates that there will be multiple choice for the particular field. But as you know, Complex types can only contain primitive properties. So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by marking all Enums as `Flags`. It was easy to proceed from there on...